# How to change the language in run time in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, localization, lang

I would like to send newsletter based on the user selected language preference.

And the preference is stored at database and can get correctly.

This is the extended controller:

```
class Front_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == false) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', "english");

            if ($this->agent->is_referral()) {
                redirect($this->agent->referrer());
            }
        }

        //set language
        $lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');
        $this->config->set_item('language', $lang);
        $this->lang->load("site", $lang);
}
```

This is the API for sending email

```
class Purchase extends Front_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $user = $this->User_model->get_user(array("id" => $user_id));
        //correctly get the perference

        //need the code to change language

        echo lang("hello"); //the "hello" should be based on the language preference
    }

});
```

I have try set the config inside test() but it seems the language is not changed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey pal, can you do a var_dump of $user. Also, the right usage of lang would be: $this->lang->line('hello') where 'Hello' would be an array in the language file.
Also, if you could please add not everything, but a few lines of the language file, that would help a lot too.

Cheers

Comment: Just to clarify: `$this->session->userdata('site_lang')` is the current web visitor language, right? But for the newsletter, you would want to get the language from the users table in database, using the `get_user` method? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you know but you get one possible solution by  [ci_i18n_library.zip](http://jeromejaglale.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=&cache=cache&media=php:ci_i18n_library_10.zip)

Visit this site for more details http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n
[image]